# Operation error transfer 300ETH to smart contract

Tags: solidity

My smart contract has a takeout ETH function.But it has some bug,I'm sure this contract address received 300ETH,But  because this variable（ethAmount） is 0, i can't get it out.Please help me.

```
function getEth(address myAd) onlyOwner public{
    msg.sender.transfer(ethAmount);
    ethAmount = 0;
}
```

Comment: We cannot really help you there. Please put your entire smart contract code.

Comment: Your question is incomplete. What's `address myAd`???

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only ETH transferral the contract code has, you will have to somehow change the value of `ethAmount` to be non-zero. If there is no way to do that, the ETH in the contract is stuck forever.

Please post your complete contract code (and maybe the contract address too) for a more definitive answer.